# Automorphisms of $\mathbb{R^*}$ as a group

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group

I was just thinking randomly about groups and cardinality of sets then I thought of the problem

> What will be the cardinality of the group of all automorphisms of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{R^*}$?

**My Attempt:** At first I thought that there's only the identity automorphism and I also got some knowledge about it from few questions over here but then I realised that the questions here was about Ring automorphisms mainly.
Then I thought if $f(x) = x^{2n+1}$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $f$ is automorphism.

So I could say that $Aut(\mathbb{R^*})$ is at least countably Infinite but then I couldn't go any further.

Can anyone give me some ideas about it?
I'd prefer if it involves simple group theory approaches.
It's okay if it's not being possible to do so.

Edit : I was also looking for functions $f$ satisfying $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$. But as I can't say anything about $f$ rather than it's bijection and preserves group structure, I could not find any form of $f$.

Comment: Do you want continuous automorphisms only?

Comment: No no just automorphisms.

Comment: I'm looking for a general overview of what the automorphisms will be and what the $Aut(\mathbb{R^*})$ will be

Comment: I recommend looking up the Cauchy functional equation. The analysis there should be transportable to this situation.

Comment: I looked it up but it seems that it is beyond my current knowledge. I haven't dealt with functional equations yet.

Comment: The Cauchy functional equation is secretly a question about homomorphisms/automorphisms of the real line in disguise.

Comment: Automorphisms must send squares to squares and elements of order $2$ to elements of order $2$, so $Aut(\mathbb{R}^{*})$ is isomorphic to $Aut(\mathbb{R}_{+})$, where $\mathbb{R}_{+}$ is the subgroup of positive real numbers.

Comment: If the Real Line is discussed with addition operation then I was able to find the form of continuous homomorphisms but here I can't go any further

Comment: @Pritam There is an isomorphism between $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^+, \cdot)$.

Comment: Forgive me if I’m wrong, but the function(s) $f(x)=\text{sign}(x)\cdot |x|^{a}$ where $a \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ should work, implying that the group has at least the cardinality of the reals.

Comment: As said above it is $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{R},+)$. Such an automorphism must be $\mathbb{Q}$-linear, so your automorphism group is the general linear goup of the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space $\mathbb{R}$. The dimension of this vector space is the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$. Taking a basis $B$, the linear group contains all permutations of $B$. The symmetric group of $B$ has cardinality the power set of $B$. So the answer is $2^{\mathbb{R}}$.

Comment: This is the answer if you accept the axiom of choice. Otherwise, if I understand this answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/16683/6506 correctly, then there is a model of ZF + discrete choice in which $\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\mathbb{R})$ consists only of the homotheties $x \to ax$ with $a \in \mathbb{R}$. So it is consistent with ZF that your automorphism group is just $\mathbb{R}^\times$.

Comment: Sorry, in my last comment it should not be "discrete choice" but "axiom of dependent choice". My point is that with the axioms of ZF alone, your question is undecidable. With the axiom of choice, it is provably $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$.

Answer (score 8):

The following expands the comments above into an answer:

First, note that the structure $(\mathbb{R}_{>0};\times)$ is isomorphic to the structure $(\mathbb{R};+)$ (think e.g. about the map $x\mapsto ln(x)$). The latter is a bit easier to think about. In particular, if you consider it as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ it's easy to see that its dimension is $2^{\aleph_0}$; any permutation of a basis extends to an automorphism of the whole, and so $Aut(\mathbb{R};+)$ has cardinality at least $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$. Since that's also an obvious upper bound (that's the number of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$), we get $$\vert Aut(\mathbb{R}_{>0};\times)\vert=2^{2^{\aleph_0}}.$$

What about $(\mathbb{R};\times)$? It turns out that **there is no real difference between $(\mathbb{R}_{>0};\times)$ and $(\mathbb{R};\times)$  as far as automorphisms are concerned**:

> Every automorphism of $(\mathbb{R}_{>0};\times)$ extends uniquely to an automorphism of $(\mathbb{R};\times)$, and every automorphism of $(\mathbb{R};\times)$ restricts to a (trivially) unique automorphism of $(\mathbb{R}_{>0};\times)$.

The key point is the following: a real number $r$ is non-negative iff it has a square root. Since this is a purely **multiplicative** property, it can't be affected by automorphisms - every automorphism of $(\mathbb{R};\times)$ must send positive reals to positive reals and negative reals to negative reals. Thinking a bit more about this gives the result above.

This gives the desired cardinality result: $$\vert Aut(\mathbb{R};\times)\vert=2^{2^{\aleph_0}}.$$

Comment: help me understand some things.... considering $\mathbb{R}$ as vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ how does this translate to finding the $Aut(\mathbb{R})$ when $(\mathbb{R},+)$ is a group structure. I understand that In order to be a vector space the set has to be an abelian group under the addition operation but I still cannot align with the concept that you used.

Comment: I also understand the concept of finding the all possible basis permutations but I can't relate this idea when I'm considering it as group only, because there's no generating set in the group $(\mathbb{R},+)$.

Comment: @Pritam You could show as an exercise that if $V_1$ and $V_2$ are two vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$, then any morphism of abelian groups $f : V_1 \to V_2$ is necessarily $\mathbb{Q}$-linear. Next, you need some theory about bases of infinite-dimensional vector spaces, like $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ here, and specifically the lemma [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/49572/6506). My argument also uses [this theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/a/32499/6506).